# Что такое метакласс в python

Tags: python, классы

Что такое метаклассы в python, как их использовать и для чего они нужны.

Comment: Вот подробная статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/145835/

Comment: Связанный вопрос [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то так как классы в питоне это тоже объекты, то метаклассы, это конструкторы(классы) классов. Именно в них надо определять порядок вызова, например, конструктора объекта функцию **init**.

В них же можно добавлять какой-то дополнительный функционал.

Создать новый класс можно самому с помощью type,

```
>>>My = type("MyClass", (), {"attribute": 5})
>>>My
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>>object = my()  # создаём экземпляр класса
>>>object
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000001F1471DE9B0>
>>>object.attribute
5
```

Если создаёте свой метакласс, то он всегда наследуется от type.

Но стоит иметь ввиду, что те кто использует метаклассы, всегда знают зачем и когда их использовать необходимо(обычно используются при разработке инструментальных средств). Если же вы задаёте такой вопрос, лучше обходить их стороной. :-)

Comment: Под инструментальными средствами Вы имеете в виду создание какого-нибудь API?

Comment: Инструментальные средства - это библиотеки всякие, движки, сервера. Хороший пример стандартная библиотека "abc".

Comment: В остальном, любые программы, даже самые сложные, можно писать без использования метаклассов.